# macOS: can I force a window to jump to another screen, using keyboard only?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

Typically, in a multi-screen setup, when you disconnect one of them (physically or through selecting a different input source), the windows that had been displayed on that monitor would be automatically brought into the available screen estate by the OS.

However this doesn't always happen so. For reasons that I don't want to dig into here because this is not the point of my question. When this occurs, it is very annoying to have to reconnect the monitor only to see that some of the windows remained "off the canvas" so to speak.

Luckily, Windows has this nice keyboard shortcut <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd> with which you can force the window to jump to another screen (it has to be frontmost, of course).

My question is: does a similar feature exist on macOS 13.x or in any of the macOS-tweaking addons? I tried to employ Stage Manager here, but it didn't help and it's something I wouldn't like to use.

*(For the curious, what kind of weird case is that: I have 2 monitors and 2 laptops. Typically I work in a full focus mode - on one of the laptops with both screens connected to it, but in some instances I need to run both laptops in parallel, and I'm talking about the moment I disconnect one of the screens)*

Comment: I presume you're using 'Displays have separate Spaces' so it's not the window that's not being reassigned, it's the actual Space itself. This isn't a mode I use, so I can't test this. Invoke Mission Control & see if the Space number exists on your current display. If so you can just switch to it. [If it was fullscreen, I'm not sure how that would appear… another thing I never use (Apple ruined Spaces when they introduced fullscreen & Stage Manager is no better) :\

Comment: @Tetsujin I wasn't even aware of the separate Spaces setting! It was indeed enabled. Gonna experiment with it! Thanks!

Comment: I recommend reading through this thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another Has some decent ideas/solutions.